# Incorrect color on hover for jQuery Mobile ListView Item

Tags: jquery-mobile

### Environment

- jQuery Mobile 1.3.0
- Ruby on Rails 3.2.12
- Chrome and Firefox latest or close to latest builds (can get exact versions if needed)
- OS X Lion 10.8.2

### Problem

Using jQuery Mobile with Rails on the back end, I am getting an odd hover effect for only list view items.  The picture below shows what a listview item looks like while hovered on.  If I add an icon/button to the right of the listview item, only the left has the issue as shown in the second picture.  All other elements with hover effects work fine.

### Evidence

Without icon, on hover (listview item):

[image: demonstrating list view highlight error]

With icon, on hover (listview item):

[image]

With icon, on hover (listview item right icon):
[image]

### Question

Why, on hover, do my listview items turn an ugly black instead of being the nice hover gradient that everything else seems to handle without issue (including an icon/button on the listview itself)?

### Code

The following is my HAML template code for the listview.

```
%ul{"data-filter" => "true", "data-inset" => "true", "data-role" => "listview"}
- @item.subitem.each do |item|
  %li{"data-theme" => "c"}
    %a{"data-prefetch" => "", "data-transition" => "slide", href: edit_item_subitem_path(@item, subitem), :rel => "external"}
      = item.text
      - if item.set
        %span.ui-li-count.ui-btn-up-c
          ✓
```

And this is what Rails/HAML generates:

```
<ul data-filter='true' data-inset='true' data-role='listview' data-split-icon='gear' data-split-theme='b'>
<li data-theme='c'>
  <a data-transition='slide' href='/items/5' rel='external'>
    Testing
    <span class='ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c'>
      2
    </span>
  </a>
  <a data-theme='c' href='/items/5/edit'>
    <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-gear ui-icon-shadow'></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

And here is the resulting "computed" source that jQuery Mobile generates (I left out the search/filter code):

```
<ul data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="b" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
<li data-theme="c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-count ui-first-child ui-last-child ui-btn-up-c">
    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-li-has-alt">
        <div class="ui-btn-text">
            <a data-transition="slide" href="/items/5" rel="external" class="ui-link-inherit">
                Testing
                <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">
                    2
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a data-theme="c" href="/items/5/edit" title="" class="ui-li-link-alt ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="notext">
        <span class="ui-btn-inner">
            <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
            <span data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="ui-btn-text">
                    </span>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

### Thanks

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need any additional information.  Also, I didn't tag this Rails as I don't think it relates to Rails, but if I should, or if it does end up being the root cause, I will tag it as such.

Comment: Have you changed `overlay-theme`. Post you listview code could help.

Comment: @Omar I did not.  I also added my list view code.

Comment: If you hover the gear icon, the same happens?

Comment: @Omar No if you look at my post, I have a screenshot of the proper behavior occurring while hovering over the gear icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, I had accidentally left the scaffolds.css.scss from when I was initially prototyping the app using the `rails scaffold` cli command.  That was causing the issue.